# php interactive mode gives no prompt

Tags: php

I'm running Windows 7. I just downloaded the "binaries and source" distribution of [Php 5.4.6](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4).

When I unzip the download and navigate into the directory and enter the command `php.exe -a` on my command line, the interactive mode appears to load but doesn't respond to my commands.

The console responds with the message `Interactive mode enabled`, followed by a blank line, but no `php >` prompt. If I enter a command like `echo "foo";`, the text I write appears, but the system does nothing with it.

What am I doing wrong?  (I tried compiling the sources myself on msys, but got the complaint: `configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.` There has got to be an easier way.)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem using php bundled with xampp on Win7 x64

Comment: I never did....

Comment: I did some digging for anyone else who winds up here. The Windows php binary is missing the readline library so it can't accept interactive input. Search for "windows" with ctrl+f on the following page to see a bunch of discussion about it: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Comment: I'm having the same problem except on Linux.